# Predict linear regression with multiple separate groups

Tags: r, dplyr, linear-regression, predict

I would like to predict values from a linear regression from multiple groups in a single dataframe.
I have found the following blogpost which ALMOST does everything I need: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/09/running-a-model-on-separate-groups/

However, I cannot combine this with the predict() function with a newdata.
For one group, I use the following:

```
m <- lm(y ~ x, df)
new_df <- data.frame(x=c(5))
predict(m, new_df)
```

this gives me the predicted value for y at x=5.

How do I do this when I have multiple groups in my df? This is what I tried:

```
df %>%
    nest(-group) %>%
    mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(.$y ~ .$x)),
           results = map(fit, predict)) %>%
    unnest(results)
```

When I try to use results = map(fit, predict(new_df)), I only get an error. Is there a way how I can pass my value for x (in this case 5) into the code above?

Ideally, I would get a new data.frame with two columns, group and the predicted y-value.

This is a sample data.frame:

```
group   x   y
g1  1   2
g1  1.5 3
g1  2   4
g1  2.3 4.4
g1  3   6
g1  3.4 6.2
g1  4.11    7
g1  4.8 7.9
g1  5   8
g1  5.3 8.2
g2  2   5
g2  2.3 4
g2  4   2.2
g2  4.4 1.9
g2  7   0.3
```

**EDIT:**

Plotting the sample data using ggplot2, I get the following plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,colour=group)) +
 geom_point() +
 stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)
```

[image: Plot]

Using the following code, I get the sought after predicted y-values:

```
predict(lm(y ~ x, df[df$group =="g1", ]), new_df)
       1 
8.180285 

predict(lm(y ~ x, df[df$group =="g2", ]), new_df)
       1 
1.732136
```

I would like to generate a new dataframe which should look something like this and contain the predicted y-value at **x=5**:

```
group   y_predict  
g1  8.180285  
g2  1.732136
```

Comment: As @Marcos Perez says below, this is a perfect case for splitting your dataframe into a list, and applying a lm function across the list elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect case to use `lapply` function. Try this:

```
linear_model <- function(x) lm(y ~ x, x)
m <- lapply(split(df,df$group),linear_model)
```

Now, you have a `list` of `linear models`. Let's use it to predict y-value of your `new_df` for all models:

```
new_df <- data.frame(x=c(5))
my_predict <- function(m) predict(m,new_df)
sapply(m,my_predict)
```

Output:

```
#     g1.1     g2.1 
# 8.180285 1.732136
```

The output is `numeric` class with names.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to do.

Is there a way to get rid of the ".1" from the output?

Comment: Sure, ".1" is becouse of `new_df` row name. So you have to rename the `new_df` row like this `new_df <- data.frame (x = c (5), row.names = c (""))`, but it's better not to do it because when `new_df` has more than one row the output is `matrix` class and column names are "g1" and "g2". Try: `new_df <- data.frame (x = c (5:6))`.

Comment: Is there also a way to get m in the form of a data.frame?

as.data.frame(m) gives the following error:   


Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame

Answer (score 3):

Using the input shown reproducibly in the Note and since we only need the fitted values we don't need to use `nest` but can just use `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(pred = fitted(lm(y ~ x))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(group, pred)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
   group    pred
   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 g1     2.47  
 2 g1     3.19  
 3 g1     3.90  
 4 g1     4.33  
 5 g1     5.33  
 6 g1     5.90  
 7 g1     6.91  
 8 g1     7.89  
 9 g1     8.18  
10 g1     8.61  
11 g2     4.41  
12 g2     4.15  
13 g2     2.63  
14 g2     2.27  
15 g2    -0.0563
```

This could also be done like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(pred = fitted(lm(y ~ x*group + 0, df))) %>%
  select(group, pred)
```

or like this using base R only:

```
transform(df, pred = fitted(lm(y ~ x*group + 0, df)))[c("group", "pred")]
```

or using lmList from nlme (which comes with R so it does not have to be installed):

```
library(dplyr)
library(nlme)

df %>%
  mutate(pred = fitted(lmList(y ~ x | group, df))) %>%
  select(group, pred)
```

or using lmList without dplyr:

```
library(nlme)

transform(df, pred = fitted(lmList(y ~ x | group, df)))[c("group", "pred")]
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
group   x   y
g1  1   2
g1  1.5 3
g1  2   4
g1  2.3 4.4
g1  3   6
g1  3.4 6.2
g1  4.11    7
g1  4.8 7.9
g1  5   8
g1  5.3 8.2
g2  2   5
g2  2.3 4
g2  4   2.2
g2  4.4 1.9
g2  7   0.3"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

### Added

Regarding comment this code produces the prediction for x = 5 by group:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(pred = predict(lm(y ~ x), list(x = 5)), .groups = "drop") %>%
  select(group, pred)
## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##   group  pred
##   <chr> <dbl>
## 1 g1     8.18
## 2 g2     1.73
```

Comment: I don't really get the output that you create. What are the values in "predict"?

I would just like to get one prediction at x=5; i.e.:

predict(lm(y ~ x, df[df$group =="g1", ]), new_df)

This gives 8.180285 which is the value I am looking for.

Comment: I guess the values in "predict" are the predicted values for the "x" values in my df? 

But how do I get just one prediction for x=5, even if I don't have a value at x=5?

Comment: See secton Added which has been added to the end.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is an estimation with varying intercepts and slopes.

#### With `lm`

You can do that directly using `lm`:

```
base = iris
names(base) = c("y", "x1", "x2", "x3", "species")

newdata = data.frame(x1 = 5, species = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"))
res_1 = lm(y ~ species/x1, base)
newdata$y = predict(res_1, newdata)
newdata
#>   x1    species        y
#> 1  5     setosa 6.091450
#> 2  5 versicolor 7.865123
#> 3  5  virginica 8.414509
```

The shortcut `species/x1` means `species + species:x1`, i.e. the factor variable and the interaction between the factor and the variable.
Thus there will be one intercept and one coefficient associated to `x1` for each group (here `species`).

Then the predict method can be used as usual which will lead to the requested result. This is done without needing loops nor `lapply`.

#### Alternative method

An alternative is to use specialized packages to estimate that kind of models, like for instance [fixest](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fixest). Since it is specialized in fixed-effects estimations, the run time will be substantially lower for large data sets.

```
library(fixest)

# Using variables with varying slopes
res_2 = feols(y ~ 1 | species[x1], base)
predict(res_2, newdata)
#>        1        2        3 
#> 6.091450 7.865123 8.414509
```

Some explanations:

- Your `group` is the variable `species` here.
- `feols` is the equivalent of `lm` but you can define fixed-effects after the pipe.
- `species[x1]` means `species` fixed-effects (i.e. one intercept per species) + `x1` having one coefficient per species (varying slopes).